# Удаление конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор-копирования, оператор-присваивания

Есть класс

```cpp
class CTest {
public:
    CTest() {};
    CTest(const CTest & src) = delete;
};
```

и есть код

```cpp
CTest t1, t2;
t1 = t2;
```

вопрос: почему код компилируется? Ведь я удаляю конструктор копирования, а значит присваивание должно быть запрещено.

**Update:**

Ошибка появляется при удалении оператора присваивания

```cpp
CTest & operator=(const CTest &) = delete;
```

получается, что при присвоении конструктор копирования не вызывается?

Comment: Насколько я помню, оператор присваивания не использует копирующий конструктор, так что удалять нужно именно `operator = `. Если вы попробуете `t1 = CTest(t2);`, компиляция не совершится. То есть, это просто разные операции

Comment: @Rabter Я правильно понимаю, что в 99% случаев код оператора присваивания должен совпадать с кодом конструктора копирования?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если бы вы написали

```
CTest t2;
CTest t1 = t2;
```

то тогда это было бы конструирование копированием, а так - у вас объект уже создан, и это - присваивание, а не копирование.

Вызывается ли при присваивании конструктор копирования? В общем случае нет - если вы не вызываете его сами.

Должен ли в 99% случаев копирующий конструктор совпадать с присваиванием? Только если в 99% случаев не требуется деструктор :) Ведь при копировании объекта еще нет, а при присваивании - уже есть, и его сначала надо удалить.

Но именно из-за схожести копирования и присваивания часто используется идиома присваивания через обмен с копией. Если вы можете написать функцию обмена внутреннего содержимого классов, типа

```
class A {
    ...
    private:
    void swap(A&);
```

которая обменивает содержимое двух объектов - вашего и переданного как аргумент, и у вас есть конструктор копирования

```
A::A(const A&)
```

то оператор присваивания можно записать как

```
A& A::operator=(const A& a)
{
    A tmp(a);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Можно для эффективности добавить проверку присваивания себе (хотя она не обязательна)

```
A& A::operator=(const A& a)
{
    if (this != &a)
    {
        A tmp(a);
        swap(tmp);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Можно копирование сделать неявным, при передаче аргумента

```
A& A::operator=(A a)
{
    swap(a);
    return *this;
}
```

Вот при использовании такой идиомы удаление конструктора копирования действительно сделает присваивание невозможным...

Comment: Да. Про деструктор при присваивании я сообразил позже